# How do camo traps work?

Tags: bloons-td-6

So I was trying to get the achievements for using powers, and in doing so I dumbed almost every power I had on the map.

*Fig-1: Power dumb game*
[image: Screenshot from a game with a lot of placeable powers on the map, including 8 camo traps]

Most powers I had not used before, but seemed pretty straight forward. That the road spikes where a bunch of spikes you could place on the track to pop bloons was quite clear. But what puzzled me was what the camo trap did.

#### What the game says

The ingame descriptions says:

*Fig-2: Camo trap description from the store*
[image: See the quote directly following this image for the transcript]

> Monkey Engineering at its finest, this trap will remove Camo state
> from the first 500 Bloons that touch it.

Now that seems pretty straight forward as well, but I remember that during this game, some of the traps I had placed on the map would turn red. It was an 80 round game, and I believe most traps were not used in the end as well. I don't think I saw the camo removal effect actually happen and I haven't touched the camo traps since this game. Could someone maybe clear up for me what the camo trap actually does and how to use it?

#### Could someone tell me:

1. What the camo trap does (remove camo from bloons right?)
2. What it means when a camo trap turns red
3. How to tactically use camo traps and what not to do with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camo Traps remove camo from Bloons that pass over them (not sure about DDTs). When doing so, they briefly turn red.
In general, don't use them; a 3-0-2 Submerge and Support, Reactor or some other towers can do the same for cheap, eventually consistently and infinitely.